# Evaluate integral $\int_{ |\vec{r}|\le R }\frac{y}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r}~'|}d^3V$

Tags: integration, physics, multiple-integral, poissons-equation

I'm working on an exercise in GR and it involves Poisson's equation with a spherical source which depends on the coordinate $y$:

$$\nabla^2 h(\vec{r})=\begin{cases}16\pi \rho\Omega y, && |\vec{r}|\leq R \\0, && |\vec{r}|\geq R\end{cases}$$

The general solution to this requires me to find this integral over the sphere of radius $R$:

$$h(\vec{r})=-4\Omega \rho\int_{|\vec{r}|\leq R}\frac{ y'}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r}~'|}d^3V'$$

I try to do this by working in cylindrical coordinates, $s$, $\theta$, and $z$, turning the integral into the following:

\begin{align*}
\int\frac{y'}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r}~'|}d^3V'&=\int\int\int\frac{s'\sin\theta(s'd\theta)ds'dz}{\sqrt{(z-z')^2+s^2+s'^2-2ss'\cos\theta}}\\
&=\int\int\int^{\theta=\pi}_{\theta=-\pi}\frac{s'^2\sin\theta ~d\theta~ ds'dz}{\sqrt{(z-z')^2+s^2+s'^2-2ss'\cos\theta}}
\end{align*}

where I have used the Law of Cosines to find $|\vec{r}-\vec{r}~'|$. I am assuming that $\vec{r}$ points along the $\theta=0$ direction (WLOG due to $\theta$ symmetry), so the polar angle between $\vec{r}$ and $\vec{r}~'$ is still $\theta$.

However, I'm stuck here, as the integrand is an odd function of $\theta$, giving me zero (which is not the correct answer) when my bounds are $\theta=-\pi$ to $\theta=\pi$.

Comment: Since the source is spherical, wouldn't it be more natural to work in spherical coordinates? You would just need to switch y and z coordinates.

Comment: For spherical coordinates the distance between $\vec{r}$ and $\vec{r}~'$ is more complicated, and I wasn't sure how to do the integral. At least in the current case, the integral is solvable for the $\theta$ part, just that it goes to zero for the bounds and I don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To evaluate the integral, assume
$$\vec r’= d(\cos\alpha\sin\beta, \sin\alpha\sin\beta, \cos\beta)$$
where $(d,\alpha,\beta)$ is the spherical coordinates of $\vec r’$. Then, rotate the axes from $(x,y,z)$ to $(u,v,w)$ such that $\vec r’$ is aligned with the $w$-axis, which leads to

$$ y= u\cos\beta\sin\alpha +v \cos\alpha +w \sin\alpha \sin \beta$$
and the integral in the $(u,v,w)$ coordinates is

$$I=\int_{|\vec{r}|\leq R}\frac{ y}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r}~'|}dxdydz
= \int_{|\vec{r}|\leq R}\frac{ w\sin\alpha\sin\beta}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r}~'|}dudvdw
$$
where the terms involving $u$ and $v$ are ignored because they do not contribute to the integral due to symmetry with respect to the $w$-axis. Then, in spherical coordinates
$$I = 2\pi \sin\alpha\sin\beta \int_0^\pi \int_0^R
\frac{r^3\cos\theta\sin\theta}{\sqrt{ d^2-2dr\cos \theta +r^2}}dr d\theta
$$
Integrate over $\theta $ and then $r$ to obtain

$$I = \frac{4\pi \sin\alpha\sin\beta }{3d^2} \int_0^R
r^4dr=  \frac{4\pi R^5\sin\alpha\sin\beta }{15 d^2} 
$$

Comment: What are the $(u,v, w) $ coordinates? Are these a different set of Cartesian coordinates? I don't understand how you get that first expression for $y$.

Comment: @HexiangChang - $(u,v,w)$ results from two axis rotations from $(x,y,z)$, which lines up $\vec r$ with the $w$-axis. The expression for $y$ is obtained after applying the rotation matrix.

Comment: Okay, I think I got that. Now, I'm not sure why $u$ and $v$ are ignored, could you elaborate on this? In fact, I don't fully understand what it means to integrate with respect to $(u,v,w)$. Does $\vec{r}~'$ still sweep around the sphere as you integrate? Or is $\vec{r}~'$ always fixed in the direction of $w$, and the $(u,v,w)$ axes somehow do the sweep?

Comment: @HexiangChang - in the $(u,v,w)$ coordinates, $\frac{u}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r}~'|}$ is odd and vanishes when integrated over the sphere. $\vec r’$ is fixed and $\vec r$ sweeps around the sphere. The sphere is the same in both coordinates.

Comment: Am I right to say that $w$ is the new "$z$" axis so $u$ and $v$ are symmetrical? Also, how can $\vec{r}~'$ be fixed and $\vec{r}$ be sweeping? Unless you have done a swap between $\vec{r}~'$ and $\vec{r}$ since in my original question $\vec{r}~'$ is the integration variable.

Comment: @HexiangChang - yes, $w$ is the new $z$. In your title, you integrate with $d^3V$, so I treated $\vec r$ as the variable. It won’t affect the result swapping them

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123100/discussion-between-hexiang-chang-and-quanto).